# Central Limit Theorem for empirical distribution

Tags: real-analysis, central-limit-theorem

I am a beginner in Real Analysis.

I know that if the samples are taken from Normal distribution, then the sum of the samples also follows a Normal distribution, irrespective of sample size. However, I want to know if there is any equivalent of this kind of limit theorem when the distribution of samples is not normal but *converges in distribution* to a Normal Distribution.

Formally,

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3...,X_n$ be independent observations from an empirical distribution function $F_n(x)$. Let $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ be the actual Normal distribution function.

Let $F_n(x)$ converges in distribution to $F(x)$.

From classical CLT, we know that if samples are taken independently from $F(x)$, the sum of the samples is also a normal distribution,$N(n\mu,{n^2\sigma}^2)$, for any sample size $n$. Can I say the same conclusion if samples are taken from $F_n(x)$, instead of $F(n)$

I did read the various versions of Functional Central Limit Theorems but could not make any progress. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just for clarification, are $F_n(x)$ random by itself (as glimpsed from the use of the word 'empirical')?

Comment: Yes, $F_n(x)$, empirical distribution function, is the distribution function associated with the empirical measure of a sample. So, it is random

Answer (score 1):

See the [Glivenko-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem) theorem. Basically, it says that under mild conditions of i.i.d sample, 
$$
F_n(x) \xrightarrow{a.s.}F(x). 
$$

Comment: Can you please try to give a formal proof?

Answer (score 1):

**This is by no means an answer, but just some small thoughts:**

---

- Let us first consider a *deterministic* sequence of distributions $(F_n)$ that satisfies the following conditions:

  > 1. $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, dF_n(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 \, dF_n(x) = \sigma^2 > 0$.
  > 2. For any $\epsilon > 0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{|x|>\epsilon \sqrt{n}} x^2 \, dF_n(x) = 0$

  If $(X_{n,1},\cdots, X_{n,n})$ are i.i.d. and have the common distribution $F_n$, then by the Lindeberg-Feller CLT (see Theorem 3.4.5 of [*Durrett*](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf), for instance) we have

  $$ Z_n := \frac{X_{n,1}+\cdots+X_{n,n}}{\sqrt{n}} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2). $$

  The above two conditions are in some sense also necessary for this convergence to occur. (For instance, see [*this article*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/215c/6b19ffa6019edaf4bb4541ef02a613486e99.pdf).)
- That being said, if $(F_n)$ is a sequence of random distributions that satisfy the condition 1 and 2 $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely, then we have the following quenched CLT:

  $$ \mathbb{P}\left[ Z_n \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) \right] = 1. $$

  Note that there are two levels of randomness. Each distribution $F_n$ is random by itself, and given a sample of $F_n$ we generate random variables $X_{n,1}, \cdots, X_{n,n}$.

  Formally, we can construct a product of probability spaces $\Omega \times \mathcal{S}$, a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\Omega$, and a family of probability measures $\{\mathsf{P}^{(\omega)}:\omega\in\Omega\}$ on $\mathcal{S}$ such that

  (i) $F_n$ are random distributions on $\Omega$, and

  (ii) $X_{n,k}$ are random variables on $\Omega\times\mathcal{S}$ such that for each given $\omega\in\Omega$, $X_{n,1},\cdots,X_{n,n}$ are i.i.d. and have the distribution $F_n(\omega)$ under the law $\mathsf{P}^{(\omega)}$.

  Now if $\omega \in \Omega$ is such that two conditions 1 and 2 are satisfies for the sample $(F_n(\omega))$, then we can apply the Lindeberg-Feller CLT to show that

  $$ Z_n := \frac{X_{n,1}+\cdots+X_{n,n}}{\sqrt{n}}, \qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathsf{P}^{(\omega)} \left[ Z_n \leq x \right] = G(x) $$

  where $G(x)$ is the CDF of the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. So if two conditions 1 and 2 are satisfies $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely, then

  $$ \mathbb{P}\left[ \left\{ \omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathsf{P}^{(\omega)} \left[ Z_n \leq x \right] = G(x) \right\} \right] = 1. $$

  In other words, $Z_n \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ under $\mathsf{P}^{(\omega)}$ is guaranteed for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: Based on the last point, $Z_n$ a.s. converges to a normal distribution. I have read elsewhere that almost sure convergence implies convergence in distribution. So can I say that $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a normal distribution - which is essentially classical CLT.

Comment: @kasa, I updated my answer. So the point is that, you have to clarify at which level you want to establish the CLT. Because $F_n$'s are random by itself, you may either 'freeze' a sample $(F_n(\omega))$ and consider CLT w.r.t. this sample (as I did above), or average out the effect of randomness on $F_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! My question was more about the assumptions you made: that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, dF_n(x) = 0 $and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 \, dF_n(x) = \sigma^2 > 0$. Can we say that this mean and $\sigma^2$ are consistent estimators or converge to the $\mu$ and $\Sigma^2$ of $F(x)$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: @kasa, I am not sure as I know nothing about consistent estimator, but relating moments of $F_n$ to those of $F$ will require certain assumptions on $(F_n)$. We already know various examples where $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, F_n(dx) \neq \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, F(dx)$ even though $F_n \Rightarrow F$. On the other hand, as you are using the word 'empirical distribution', I guess that you are forming them in a very specific way that might possibly improve the situation.